# MySQL Query Fails When Selecting Multiple user Advanced Payment Which worked fine for Single user

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table Structure

[image]

Here I am using the pay type to determine the transaction type

1  -  Advance Payment
2  -  Payment

Here is the sample data

[image]

```
SELECT SUM(upay_amount)
FROM user_payment
WHERE upay_status=1 AND upay_id >
    (
        SELECT MAX(upay_id) FROM user_payment WHERE upay_usr_id=3 AND upay_status=2
    )
    AND upay_usr_id=3
GROUP by upay_usr_id
```

It worked fine with output

```
438359
```

But when i tried to generalize the query I am stuck cause the subquery which is responsible for returning the max of upay_id with status=2 returns only one row in case of single user, because i am specifying the user id

BUT WHAT DO ? IF I WANT TO RETURN THE ADVANCE PAYMENT TAKEN BY EVERY USER INSTEAD OF JUST ONE??

Comment: Can you please show us some suggested output?  This question is very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the subquery to FROM and add GROUP BY user id to find maximum for each user. Then join it and use the MAX in WHERE. Like this

```
SELECT SUM(upay_amount)
FROM user_payment up INNER JOIN (
        SELECT upay_usr_id, MAX(upay_id) grMax
        FROM user_payment 
        WHERE upay_status=2
        GROUP BY upay_usr_id
    ) gr ON up.upay_usr_id=gr.upay_usr_id
WHERE upay_status=1 AND upay_id > gr.grMax
GROUP BY up.upay_usr_id
```